# Elasticsearch return document ids while doing aggregate query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get an array of elasticsearch document id while group by, i.e

Current output

```
"aggregations": {,
        "types": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Text Document",
                    "doc_count": 3310
                },
                {
                    "key": "Unknown",
                    "doc_count": 15
                },
                {
                    "key": "Document",
                    "doc_count": 13
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Desired output

```
"aggregations": {,
        "types": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Text Document",
                    "doc_count": 3310,
                    "ids":["doc1","doc2", "doc3"....]
                },
                {
                    "key": "Unknown",
                    "doc_count": 15,
                    "ids":["doc11","doc12", "doc13"....]
                },
                {
                    "key": "Document",  
                    "doc_count": 13
                    "ids":["doc21","doc22", "doc23"....]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is possible in elasticsearch or not,
below is my aggregation query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "types": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "docType",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Elasticsearch version:
6.3.2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) which will return all documents under an aggregation. Using source filtering you can select fields under hits

**Query:**

```
  "aggs": {
    "district": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "docType",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "_source": ["ids"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, is it possible to hide metadata of the document i.e  "_index", "_type", "_id", "_score", "_source". I just need _id of doc not all other metadata

Comment: @RaghuChahar unfortunately no, metadata cannot be removed

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, another solution is to create a custom key value using a script to create a string of delineated values from the doc, including the id. It may not be pretty, but you can then parse it out later - and if you just need something minimal like the doc id, it may be worth it.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "types": {
            "terms": {
                "script": "doc['docType'].value+'::'+doc['_id'].value",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```